# Get value of number input from Jquery, used nicenumber() for number input

Tags: jquery, numbers, dynamic-programming

i have added nicenumber for my dynamically generated  number input from repeater and i want to get values that was changed. Now ID of input is generated dynamically its little difficult for me to get the jquery setup for change function. What will the best way to get data from the input via Jquery.

i have tried onchanged on input,
$('[type="number"]').click(function () { });

```
  $(":input").bind('keyup mouseup change', function () {
  alert("changed");
  });
```

and nothing seem to work. :(

```
<asp:Repeater ID="FoodGroupItems" runat="server" DataSourceID="FoodGroupDS">
<ItemTemplate>
                                      <input type="number" id="<%# Eval("ItemID")%>" value='<%# QuantityVal(Eval("ItemID"))%>' min="0" max="20" style="width:5ch;">

         <label Class="radioAlign"><b><%# Eval("ItemTitle") %></b></label> 

            <label>&nbsp; $<%# Eval("itemPrice").ToString().Substring(0, Eval("itemPrice").ToString().Length() - 2) %></label>
                                       <br />
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

i have a Repeater where i am populating items
input is using nicenumber to select the quantity of the food.

```
<label Class="radioAlign"><b><%# Eval("ItemTitle") %></b></label>
```

is displaying Item title/name

and  last label is displaying price

```
  <label>&nbsp; $<%# Eval("itemPrice").ToString().Substring(0, Eval("itemPrice").ToString().Length() - 2) %></label>
```

which looks like this

[image: [1]: https://imgur.com/a/ROuXxb9 "Order layout"]

i want to get ID of the Item and quantity to be fetched in the jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [`.nicenumber()` source](https://github.com/joshua-s/jquery.nice-number/blob/db6291cb9244f666d5f56ce9d86aa85797ad1326/dist/jquery.nice-number.js#L68) it looks like they are firing an `input` event on the inputs.

So doing something like this should work...

```
$(document).on('change keydown keyup cut paste input', 'input[type="number"]', function() {
  alert("changed");
});
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that. I had simile code with 'input' but it was keep giving me alert popup even when i move my move over the button.I was hoping not to change the base code but i end up changing the source to get it working only on click. I removed 'mouseleave' event from the source code and kept 'mousedown' and 'mouseup' only. This seems to be working now as expected. Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `onIncrement` and `onDecrement` with `.nicenumber()`

```
$(function () {
    $('input=[type="number"]').niceNumber({
        onIncrement: function () {
            // your code
        },
        onDecrement: function () {
            // your code
        },
    });
 });
```